# Non-selective partial index on nulls

Tags: postgresql, indexing, query-optimization, postgresql-9.3, partial-index

I've just found an interesting partial index in my db:

```
CREATE INDEX orders_idx
  ON orders
  USING btree
  (status)
  WHERE status IS NULL;
```

As you see it's completely non-selective and imho completely not usefull, or am I missing something?

Comment: Depends on how many rows have `NULL` in the status column. If there are only a few, this could be helpful for a `where status is null` condition.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: That should pass as answer.

Comment: Also: If all your queries that need an index on `status` have the WHERE  condition `status IS NULL`, the index is useful even for a big number of NULLs - as long as its not the vast majority of rows.

Comment: the amount of nulls in status column is decreasing. i need to run some more tests on that. thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have queries where you filter by status is null, (as mentioned in the comments,) or need to run maintenance on the entries where the status is null, this index may be useful.

For example from a project  I used to work on (that didn't have this type of index,) I had an import process that keeps a log/queue. It sets status to queued when starting, running while in progress, and sets status to complete when finished - but sets it to null if there is an error. That will need to be cleaned up, because items in other tables will not have been correctly set to the values needed. I needed to routinely query on status is null to diagnose specific problems, or run cleanup scripts so the database wasn't full of partial imports.

Comment: yes, it's similar situation in my case. I was wondering if index maintance in this case isn't too expensive comparing to search cost.

Comment: It's the kind of thing you need to profile, I think.

In our case, I think it was better to have the fixed overhead for index maintenence, to reduce the very heavy load that otherwise hit when we did cleanup, which would break things otherwise. (It was not a great system, in some ways.)